# What's the source for the Cheirim of York?

Tags: history, cherem

Regarding the massacre of the Jews which took place at Cliffords Tower in York, 1190. It is said that as a result of this incident, a cheirem was placed on York forbidding people to sleep there overnight.

Can anyone provide a source for this cheirem?
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.yorkcastle.com/media/mishpacha172.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiR16z7lv_mAhWEq1kKHdBTBiIQFjAHegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2u2IQFlXW0uIDRbnm6Hv8y

Comment: “It is said” by whom?

Comment: This article has a comment which claims it is relatively recent https://www.haaretz.com/jewish/1.5205561

Comment: Its mentioned in a lot of Jewish history recordings of the event.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.yorkcastle.com/media/mishpacha172.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiR16z7lv_mAhWEq1kKHdBTBiIQFjAHegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2u2IQFlXW0uIDRbnm6Hv8y

Comment: 1. If you’re responding to me, please put @ in front of my name somewhere in the comment, as in @Prof.Purim. 2. Please [edit] that information into your question, rather than leaving it in comments which might be deleted at some point.

Comment: @rosends That article in fact says that there the cherem is a myth.

Comment: @magicker72 yes, but one of the comments says "The cherem, incidentally, if it ever did exist, is supposed to have been drawn up in the 18C - so the legend is far more recent than the events themselves. " This might direct the questioner to a different era or set of resources.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/cheirem-on-york#post-1066045), it might be in the Pinkas of Vaad Arba Aratzot. I'm commenting here to write that having thoroughly checked, it's not there (although a cherem on Ukraine post ת"ח-ת"ט was enacted and eventually canceled and for a while there was also one on Jaroslav).